# Tor source code brief explanation

Tags: source-code

Is there any way I can see what each file does in Tor source code? A simple file with a list for example?I do not want to read and surf through whole code.

Comment: Your question have my upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitweb allows you to [browse through the code](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree). Especially the [`src/or`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/tree/HEAD:/src/or) directory has relevant source code. Some of the files contain a description what this file does:

```
 /**
 * \file directory.c
 * \brief Code to send and fetch directories and router
 * descriptors via HTTP. Directories use dirserv.c to generate the
 * results; clients use routers.c to parse them.
 **/
```

This belongs to[`src/or/directory.c`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/HEAD:/src/or/directory.c).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this way, for example:

> (sorry, do not know how to hide it)
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/contrib/id_to_fp.c]**
>
> Helper for directory authority ops. When somebody sends us a private key, this utility converts the private key into a fingerprint so you can de-list that fingerprint
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/ext/strlcat.c]**
>
> Appends src to string dst of size siz
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/ext/strlcpy.c]**
>
> Copy src to string dst of size siz
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/ext/eventdns.c]**
>
> Async DNS Library
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/ext/tinytest_demo.c]**
>
> Welcome to the example file for tinytest
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/ext/tinytest.c]**
>
> tinytest.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/ext/curve25519_donna/curve25519-donna-c64.c]**
>
> Curve25519 elliptic curve, public key function
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/ext/curve25519_donna/curve25519-donna.c]**
>
> Curve25519 elliptic curve, public key function
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/ext/OpenBSD_malloc_Linux.c]**
>
> malloc.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/crypto_format.c]**
>
> Formatting and parsing code for crypto-related data structures
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/crypto_curve25519.c]**
>
> Wrapper code for a curve25519 implementation
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/log.c]**
>
> Functions to send messages to log files or the console
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/util_codedigest.c]**
>
> Return a string describing the digest of the source files in src/common/
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/procmon.c]**
>
> Process-termination monitor functions
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/container.c]**
>
> Implements a smartlist (a resizable array) along with helper functions to use smartlists. Also includes hash table implementations of a string-to-void* map, and of a digest-to-void* map
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/di_ops.c]**
>
> Functions for data-independent operations
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/compat_libevent.c]**
>
> Wrappers to handle porting between different versions of libevent
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/memarea.c]**
>
> Implementation for memarea_t, an allocator for allocating lots of small objects that will be freed all at once
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/crypto.c]**
>
> Wrapper functions to present a consistent interface to public-key and symmetric cryptography operations from OpenSSL
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/tortls.c]**
>
> Wrapper functions to present a consistent interface to TLS, SSL, and X.509 functions from OpenSSL
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/address.c]**
>
> Functions to use and manipulate the tor_addr_t structure
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/torgzip.c]**
>
> A simple in-memory gzip implementation
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/aes.c]**
>
> Implements a counter-mode stream cipher on top of AES
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/mempool.c]**
>
> This is an implementation of memory pools for Tor cells
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/util.c]**
>
> Common functions for strings, IO, network, data structures, process control
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/common/compat.c]**
>
> Wrappers to make calls more portable
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_config.c]**
>
> test_config.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_containers.c]**
>
> test_containers.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_introduce.c]**
>
> test_introduce.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test.c]**
>
> Unit tests for many pieces of the lower level Tor modules
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_util.c]**
>
> test_util.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_dir.c]**
>
> test_dir.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/bench.c]**
>
> Benchmarks for lower level Tor modules
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_ntor_cl.c]**
>
> test_ntor_cl.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_microdesc.c]**
>
> test_microdesc.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_crypto.c]**
>
> test_crypto.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_addr.c]**
>
> test_addr.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_cell_formats.c]**
>
> test_cell_formats.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_replay.c]**
>
> test_replay.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_data.c]**
>
> test_data.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test-child.c]**
>
> Trivial test program which prints out its command line arguments
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/test/test_pt.c]**
>
> test_pt.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/networkstatus.c]**
>
> Functions and structures for handling network status documents as a client or cache
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/dns.c]**
>
> Implements a local cache for DNS results for Tor servers
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/rendcommon.c]**
>
> Rendezvous implementation: shared code between introducers, services, clients, and rendezvous points
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/config.c]**
>
> Code to parse and interpret configuration files
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/replaycache.c]**
>
> Self-scrubbing replay cache for rendservice.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/command.c]**
>
> Functions for processing incoming cells
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/transports.c]**
>
> Pluggable Transports related code
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/connection_or.c]**
>
> Functions to handle OR connections, TLS handshaking, and cells on the network
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/status.c]**
>
> Keep status information and log the heartbeat messages
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/circuitbuild.c]**
>
> The actual details of building circuits
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/circuitlist.c]**
>
> Manage the global circuit list
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/routerset.c]**
>
> A routerset specifies constraints on a set of possible routerinfos
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/confparse.c]**
>
> Functions to parse config options
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/addressmap.c]**
>
> A client-side struct to remember requests to rewrite addresses to new addresses
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/nodelist.c]**
>
> A list of all the nodes
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/circuitmux.c]**
>
> Circuit mux/cell selection abstraction
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/rendmid.c]**
>
> Implement introductions points and rendezvous points
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/config_codedigest.c]**
>
> Return a string describing the digest of the source files in src/or/
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/statefile.c]**
>
> statefile.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/routerparse.c]**
>
> Code to parse and validate router descriptors and directories
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/dirserv.c]**
>
> Directory server core implementation
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/connection_edge.c]**
>
> Handle edge streams
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/dnsserv.c]**
>
> Implements client-side DNS proxy server code
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/onion_tap.c]**
>
> Functions to implement the original Tor circuit extension handshake
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/buffers.c]**
>
> Implements a generic interface buffer
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/rendclient.c]**
>
> Client code to access location-hidden services
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/ntmain.c]**
>
> ntmain.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/onion_ntor.c]**
>
> onion_ntor.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/relay.c]**
>
> Handle relay cell encryption/decryption, plus packaging and  receiving from circuits, plus queuing on circuits
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/fp_pair.c]**
>
> fp_pair.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/hibernate.c]**
>
> Functions to close listeners, stop allowing new circuits, etc
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/circuituse.c]**
>
> Launch the right sort of circuits and attach streams to them
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/entrynodes.c]**
>
> Code to manage our fixed first nodes for various functions
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/router.c]**
>
> OR functionality, including key maintenance, generating and uploading server descriptors, retrying OR connections
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/connection.c]**
>
> General high-level functions to handle reading and writing on connections
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/reasons.c]**
>
> Convert circuit, stream, and orconn error reasons to and/or from strings and errno values
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/microdesc.c]**
>
> microdesc.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/tor_main.c]**
>
> Stub module containing a main() function. Allows unit test binary to link against main.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/main.c]**
>
> Toplevel module. Handles signals, multiplexes between connections, implements main loop, and drives scheduled events
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/circuitmux_ewma.c]**
>
> EWMA circuit selection as a circuitmux_t policy
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/policies.c]**
>
> Code to parse and use address policies and exit policies
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/cpuworker.c]**
>
> Implements a farm of 'CPU worker' processes to perform CPU-intensive tasks in another thread or process, to not interrupt the main thread
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/directory.c]**
>
> Code to send and fetch directories and router descriptors via HTTP
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/control.c]**
>
> Implementation for Tor's control-socket interface
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/onion_fast.c]**
>
> Functions implement the CREATE_FAST circuit handshake
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/channeltls.c]**
>
> channel_t concrete subclass using or_connection_t
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/rendservice.c]**
>
> The hidden-service side of rendezvous functionality
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/dirvote.c]**
>
> Functions to compute directory consensus, and schedule voting
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/onion.c]**
>
> Functions to queue create cells, wrap the various onionskin types, and parse and create the CREATE cell and its allies
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/circuitstats.c]**
>
> Global list of circuit build times
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/geoip.c]**
>
> Functions related to maintaining an IP-to-country database
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/channel.c]**
>
> OR-to-OR channel abstraction layer
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/routerlist.c]**
>
> Code to maintain and access the global list of routerinfos for known servers
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/or/rephist.c]**
>
> Basic history and "reputation" functionality to remember which servers have worked in the past, how much bandwidth we've  been using, which ports we tend to want, and so on
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/tools/tor-gencert.c]**
>
> tor-gencert.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/tools/tor-fw-helper/tor-fw-helper.c]**
>
> The main wrapper around our firewall helper logic
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/tools/tor-fw-helper/tor-fw-helper-upnp.c]**
>
> The implementation of our UPnP firewall helper
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/tools/tor-fw-helper/tor-fw-helper-natpmp.c]**
>
> The implementation of our NAT-PMP firewall helper
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/tools/tor-resolve.c]**
>
> tor-resolve.c
>
> ---
>
> **[tor-2ee56e4/src/tools/tor-checkkey.c]**
>
> tor-checkkey.c
>
> ---

But there might be stuff that you must read from source code files.

Comment: Interesting, your answer have my upvote.